# How to insert HTML into Summernote WYSIWYG editor?

Tags: php, summernote

I need to add HTML using Summernote WYSIWYG editor.

It appears that by default if you type something into it and you check the source, and even in database, you have:

```
<p>test</p>
```

I want to add some bootstrap div's using this, but it does not save. I do not trim the content as it is being added only from administrator panel, so it is safe as I am the only admin and there will be no more.

Field that is saving in database is of LONGTEXT type.

Any ideas why this is happening ?!

EDIT: Here is how the current info is stored in database:

[image]

Comment: i think summernote change < and > into their relatives html entitys, i dont'know why you wanto to add some divs into a text note, but some time ago i've done something similar by reading and modify the script adding my personal button for adding some html elements

Comment: Hello, I want to add html because I am creating dynamic site pages that are added from admin panel and I want to style them with bootstrap.

Comment: Apparently it works great when you just enter their pre-made tables and such from the menu. I also tried to input direct <div> into the editor, it took them. I tried to add them into the code view and that is why it did not work.